# How to get inner xml from string containing XMl

Tags: c#, xml, string, parsing, split

So if I have this sample string with xml within.

```
"<bookstore>
   <book genre='autobiography' publicationdate='1981-03-22' ISBN='1-861003-11-0'>
       <title>The Autobiography of Benjamin Franklin</title>
       <author age="40">
           <first-name>Benjamin</first-name>
           <last-name>Franklin</last-name>
       </author>
       <author age="56">
           <first-name>Barack</first-name>
           <last-name>Obama</last-name>
       </author>
       <price>8.99</price>
   </book>
 </bookstore>"
```

I want from it to make two different strings as follows:

```
"<author age="40">
           <first-name>Benjamin</first-name>
           <last-name>Franklin</last-name>
       </author>"
```

and

```
"<author age="56">
           <first-name>Barack</first-name>
           <last-name>Obama</last-name>
       </author>"
```

because I want to put them in List. I tried using Split but with no result

Comment: Open it with XmlDocument and loop through the contents.

Comment: But this will get the values. I need to make small xmls from it in string form

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do this in one line with LINQ:

```
List<string> list = XDocument.Parse(xmlString)
                     .Descendants("author")
                     .Select(x => x.ToString())
                     .ToList();
```